# Gallery of Qt stylesheets?

Tags: qt

Is there a go-to resource for Qt stylesheets?

In the [qt.io](https://forum.qt.io/topic/28804/download-qt-style-sheet-files/6) forums where this same question was asked, several respondents mentioned they were going to create a gallery or similar, but most links are dead and there doesn't seem to be a primary resource.